# Convert Optimizely jQuery Object to String

Tags: jquery, object, optimizely

Getting an [object Object] error on linkOne within $related. I tried using JSON.stringify(), but that didn't seem to work. Below is the code thusfar:

```
var $secondParagraph = $('.entry-content > p:eq(1)');

var linkOneLink = $(".pagealignleft > .bottom > a:eq(0)").attr("href");
var linkOneText= $(".pagealignleft > .bottom > a:eq(0) > span:eq(0)");
var linkOne = ['<a href=\"' +  linkOneLink + '\">' + linkOneText + '</a>'].join('').toString();

var $related = [
    '<div class="relatedOne">',
  '<p>',
  '<br />',
  '<span class="optTitle">Related Content: </span>',
  linkOne,
  ', ',
  '<a href="">the Collection</a> ',
  '</p>',
  '</div>'
].join('');


if ($secondParagraph.length) {
    $secondParagraph.append($related);
}
$(".optTitle").css({"color":"#dd4b39","font-size":"16px"});
$(".relatedOne a").css({"color":"#555","font-size":"16px","text-decoration":"underline"});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't getting the contents of the link, just the link itself. Change

`var linkOneText= $(".pagealignleft > .bottom > a:eq(0) > span:eq(0)");`

to

`var linkOneText= $(".pagealignleft > .bottom > a:eq(0) > span:eq(0)").text();`

Answer (score 2):

```
var linkOneText= $(".pagealignleft > .bottom > a:eq(0) > span:eq(0)");
```

This returns a jQuery object. I think you're trying to get a string value here, maybe the contents of this element? So maybe add `.html()` or `.text()` at the end?